# Are Machine Learning Weather Prediction models better than classic weather forecast?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, forecasting, difference

We all know that, there are weather prediction models and case studies. But I don't understand the reason, why people trust them rather than weather forecast on TV.

I mean, what is advantages of Machine Learning weather prediction over classic weather forecast?

Comment: I would expect that the Machine Learning does not have access to all data the human user of a model can use.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a meteorologist but in my humble opinion, [Numerical Weather Prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_weather_prediction) and especially WRF (stands for Weather Research and Forecasting - a high resolution & mesoscale model, unlike the old single-layer barotropic models) still makes decent predictions against ML in general.

One area comes to my mind that ML is doing better is precipitation nowcast (very short term forecasts - up to 2 hours). [Deepmind](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03854-z) just released a study recently.

Also you can see how accurate the global NWP yourself from the open datasets (i.e. https://www.ecmwf.int/)

Comment: Good points! Thank you for sharing.